# Telerik rad controls not working when debug = false

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have been having some trouble releasing code that uses Telerik rad controls.

The code works fine in a "debug" build configuration... but when I change it to "release" they stop working.

If I then change the debug config setting to true (whilst running a release build configuration) it also works fine.

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
```

The error I get is:

> Telerik is undefined

Below is an example of some code that won't work when the config setting debug="false" for a release build.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server"></ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>
            <telerik:RadTreeView ID="RadTreeView1" runat="server">
                <Nodes>
                    <telerik:RadTreeNode runat="server" Text="Root RadTreeNode1">
                        <Nodes>
                            <telerik:RadTreeNode runat="server" Text="Child RadTreeNode 1"></telerik:RadTreeNode>
                            <telerik:RadTreeNode runat="server" Text="Child RadTreeNode 2"></telerik:RadTreeNode>
                            <telerik:RadTreeNode runat="server" Text="Child RadTreeNode 3"></telerik:RadTreeNode>
                            <telerik:RadTreeNode runat="server" Text="Child RadTreeNode 4"></telerik:RadTreeNode>
                        </Nodes>
                    </telerik:RadTreeNode>
                    <telerik:RadTreeNode runat="server" Text="Root RadTreeNode2"></telerik:RadTreeNode>
                    <telerik:RadTreeNode runat="server" Text="Root RadTreeNode3">
                        <Nodes>
                            <telerik:RadTreeNode runat="server" Text="Child RadTreeNode 1"></telerik:RadTreeNode>
                            <telerik:RadTreeNode runat="server" Text="Child RadTreeNode 2"></telerik:RadTreeNode>
                            <telerik:RadTreeNode runat="server" Text="Child RadTreeNode 3"></telerik:RadTreeNode>
                        </Nodes>
                    </telerik:RadTreeNode>
                    <telerik:RadTreeNode runat="server" Text="Root RadTreeNode4"></telerik:RadTreeNode>
                    <telerik:RadTreeNode runat="server" Text="Root RadTreeNode5"></telerik:RadTreeNode>
                </Nodes>
            </telerik:RadTreeView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This occurs in our main system and in a single page website (above) on more than one machine.

Can any of you please advise?

Thanks

Edit:

The script references aren't being added to the html.

The code is too big to upload, but here are a couple of images...

(debug == true)

[image]

(debug == false)

[image]

Comment: Does it occur for all machines?  Also, if you have a developer tool (IE + dev plugin, fiddler, firefox + firebug), look to see if the script files are being requested and downloaded, or if they are returning a 404.

Comment: Yes, it occurs for all machines. The script files are downloading fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try allowing all users for TelerikWebResource.axd, or look at this [telerik resource](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload-troubleshooting.html) to see if this has your answer.

Comment: I can navigate to site/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd without a problem.

Comment: Telerik is undefined is usually because a script using it occurs before the script that defines it, or the script it's defined in isn't loading at all.  That's what you would have to research.

Answer (score 0):

Try the scripts CDN http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/scriptmanager-cdn-support.html
so that webresources are avoided as much as possible

Also, have a look at these sections:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-troubleshooting.html#telerik-is-undefined

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-troubleshooting.html#Sys-is-undefined

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-troubleshooting.html#radscriptmanager-login-page-error

You can also see if the LoadScriptsBeforeUI property of the ScriptManager makes a difference.

And make sure your web.config has all handlers. Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="Telerik.ScriptManager.TelerikCdn" value="Disabled" />
        <add key="Telerik.StyleSheetManager.TelerikCdn" value="Disabled" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" />
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <httpHandlers>

            <add path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
            <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
            <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
            <add path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
            <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false" />
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
        <!-- Only needed if RadUpload is used in the site -->
        <!--    <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule" /> -->
        <!-- Only needed if RadCompression is used in the site -->
        <!--    <add name="RadCompression" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompression" />  -->

        </httpModules>
    </system.web>

    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <!-- Only needed if RadUpload is used in the site -->
        <!--    <remove name="RadUploadModule" /> -->
        <!--    <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule" preCondition="integratedMode" /> -->
        <!-- Only needed if RadCompression is used in the site -->
        <!--    <remove name="RadCompression" /> -->
        <!--    <add name="RadCompression" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompression" preCondition="integratedMode" /> -->

        </modules>
        <handlers>

            <remove name="ChartImage_axd" />
            <add name="ChartImage_axd" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" />
            <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" />
            <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <remove name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" />
            <add name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" />
            <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add combineScripts="false" to your `<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server"`> tag.

Per this article:

http://www.telerik.com/forums/telerik-ui-for-asp-net-ajax-and-ajax-control-toolkit

Answer (score 0):

Better replace the ajax:ToolkitScriptManager with either asp:ScriptManager or telerik:RadScriptManager